# What do the breakpoints created from exception breakpoint mean?

Tags: swift, xcode, breakpoints

I have been getting a Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT when trying to fetch core data, so I created an exception breakpoint. When I ran the program it immediately crashed and added two more breakpoints:

```
objc_exception_throw in libobjc.A.dylib
```

And:

```
__cxa_throw in libc++abi.dylib
```

What do these mean? How can I fix these?

FYI: I am new to Swift.

Here is the best way I can explain the code:

There is one file, CoreDataHandler, with 5 functions:

```
private class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    ...
}

class func savePhotoObject(locationCoordinateLatitude: Double, locationCoordinateLongitude: Double, locationLocality: String, dateCreated: Date, discription: String, photo: Data) -> Bool {
    ...
}

class func fetchPhotoObject() -> [CreatedPhotoPost]? {
    ...
}

class func saveTextObject(locationCoordinateLatitude: Double, locationCoordinateLongitude: Double, locationLocality: String, dateCreated: Date, backgroundColorRed: Int, backgroundColorGreen: Int, backgroundColorBlue: Int, text: String) -> Bool {
    ...
}

class func fetchTextObject() -> [CreatedTextPost]? {
    ...
}
```

Then in another file when a continue button is pressed this happens:

```
CoreDataHandler.savePhotoObject(locationCoordinateLatitude: lat, locationCoordinateLongitude: lng, locationLocality: cityState, dateCreated: date, discription: discriptionBox.text!, photo: selectedImageData!)
```

Then a file is opened by the continue button as well and this happens:

```
post = CoreDataHandler.fetchPhotoObject()

for i in post! {
    ...
}
```

This same process is repeated with the saveTextObject() and fetchTextObject().

Hope this helps.

Comment: How  can we help you if we can't see the code? Please click on edit and paste the code in, select it and type control-K (command-K on mac) to format it.

Comment: Well the code it on multiple 5 different pages. What do you need?

Comment: Spend some time thinking about an answer to that question, and provide that code. That's the best advice I can give you.

Comment: There I added some of the code that I have, but there is obviously a lot more. This is a small part of a very large project. I hope that helps. But, the crash is happing at launch and in the AppDelegate File.